# Replace words in a Word template

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am trying to replace strings in a Word document with cells from my Excel sheet.

The result of the updated (but not saved) Word document should then be used as the body of an e-mail.

When I press debug it highlights `Replacement.Text = Samenstellen.Cells(15, 2).Value`.

```vb
Sub sendMail()

Dim ol As Outlook.Application
Dim olm As Outlook.MailItem
Dim wd As Word.Application
Dim doc As Word.Document

Set ol = New Outlook.Application
Set olm = ol.CreateItem(olMailItem)
Set wd = New Word.Application

wd.Visible = True

Set doc = wd.Documents.Open("\\file-wpv01.office.intern\home$\jslagers\Desktop\offerte\TemplateofferteZiggo.docx")
 
With wd.Selection.Find
    .Text = "<<NAAMKLANT>>"
    .Replacement.Text = Samenstellen.Cells(15, 2).Value
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
End With

With olm
    .Display
    .To = "mailhere"
    .Subject = "Offerte"

    Set Editor = .GetInspector.WordEditor
    Editor.Content.Paste
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How is it not working?

Comment: SImply nothing happens, when I press debug it says:.highlights this sentence in yellow: Replacement.Text = Samenstellen.Cells(15, 2).Value

Comment: Where are you running the code from? Excel/Outlook/Word? What is Samenstellen supposed to refer to?

Comment: Replace with cells (i.e., Excel objects) or with the text result in cells?

Comment: Sounds like a job for mailmerge. No code required...

Comment: Did you try to debug the code step-by-step? Do you get any errors on your way?